# How to check the listbox is checked or not

Tags: vb6

How to check whether the listbox is checked or not

list1

```
checkbox item

checkbox   Raja
checkbox   Raman
checkbox   Vijay
```

From the list1 i want to check whethere checkbox is checked or not

How to write a code in vb6

Need Vb6 code Help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If List1.SelCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Some items are selected"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry,no items are selected !"
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If you want to find out the selected items, you could do it like this:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1    'loop through the items in the ListBox
        If List1.Selected(i) = True Then    ' if the item is selected(checked)
            MsgBox List1.List(i)        ' display the item
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```